# LocalHost:3000 not loading my Meteor app

Tags: meteor

Hey so I'm working through the tutorial for writing an app with Meteor on a Windows laptop. The localhost:3000 is not loading my app. Curious if anybody has an idea as to solutions? thanks

Comment: `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` in Chrome?

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

Open command prompt/terminal and change the working directory to your app directory(simple-todos in my case). So,

```
cd simple-todos
```

Setup port for your meteor app:

```
meteor --port 3000
```

Or a different port using:

```
meteor --port 3030
```

If you have a settings file (settings.json) for the meteor app, you can start the app using the command below:

```
meteor --settings settings.json
```

If successfully created the port, you will get a response like this:

> [[[[[ ~/public_html/simple-todos ]]]]]
>
> => Started proxy.
>   => Started MongoDB.
>   => Started your app.
>
> => App running at: http://localhost:3000/

Answer (score 5):

Try `127.0.0.1:3000`. I had the same problem (although I am on a mac) this morning. Localhost wouldn't run. Switched to `127.0.0.1` and it works.

Answer (score 3):

```
0.0.0.0:3000
```

or `meteor --port 3030` (set the port 3030).

And check your `mongodb/node` install.

Comment: couldn't you format and explain your answer well and more?

Answer (score 1):

In my config 127.0.0.1:3000 is working as well. However, I found out that I have a different configuration in my hosts file. I have set 127.0.0.1 to www.localhost.com (because I'm also running Magento locally, which needs this).

www.localhost.com:3000 is working for me.